# Poor parallel performance of f# application when parallelizing over independent, calculation intensive tasks

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, f#

I am working on an application that on paper lends itself very well to parallelization, however, I do not get the performance, I expect.

Schematically, the application works by:

1. independently projecting a number of subjects (around 250 k) a period forward given some initial conditions
2. aggregating results across sujects, setting new initial conditions
3. repeat (app. 1200 times)
4. do global aggregation

Doing this sequentially takes around 9 mins real time.

I have implemented a parallelization over subjects (Array.Parallel), meaning that step 1 works in full parallel and that step 2 uses a map-reduce approach. On a 16 core machine, this takes the time to app 1:15 mins. I think this is ok given the fact that I will pay the overhead of parallelization 2400 times per calculation (once for step 1, once for step 2 per repeat).

Now, the application will most often be run in batches of several calculations, so I thought to do a parallelization over calculations (PSeq but I also tried Array.Parallel). This should be a much more effective parallelization, given that calculations will be almost fully independent (there will be some sharing of data, but no writing to same objects/locations). So the overhead will only have to be paid once per batch.

Unfortunately, reality is that running a batch of 16 calculations on my 16 core machine takes app. 35 minutes (ideally, it should take 9 + \epsilon minutes, I believe).

I suspect the problem is related to GC, so I have tried various GC settings. Mostly, these have done very little but I had the best results setting the `GCSettings.LatencyMode` equal to `GCLatencyMode.Batch` and using the environment variable `COMPlus_GCRetainVM=1`. The effect of this was pretty limited though (1-2 mins). I use server GC.

I am not running out of memory: I have 96 GB RAM but depending on aforementioned settings I use between 17-40 GB tops.

Due to my technical setup I cannot really profile my app on the 16 core server, which makes life difficult. I can see the windows performance monitor and the total memory usage depends heavily on  the GC settings. Standard is around 30 GBs but the Batch setting brings this down to under 20. The CPU utilisation is generally pretty high: 80 to 90 percent. The Batch setting does cause quite a few interruptions with low CPU utilisation. Maybe once every 30 secs.

I have tried some profiling (JetBrains dotTrace Timeline) on another machine with fewer cores and a smaller data set, it seems that the computer in this setup uses 10 times as much time on native code as it does when running sequentially (not too much time is spent waiting for GC across threads so I suspect effects of concurrent individual core GC).

Anyway, I am running out of ideas, so any input is welcome.

Comment: With the question phrased at such a high level, I don't think there's much practical advice that can be offered. You should identify which functions are taking the most time to run, allocating lots of memory etc. With specific questions around problem functions you can probably get a good answer from the community.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know, this is rather high level but I guess that is also the heart of the matter. If any particular function was the issue, I should have found it by now. Really, the question is about parallelization and possible approaches to improve/analyze this, other angles to consider etc. As mentioned, I'm alright with sequential performance and even my (on paper) not so efficient parallelization.

Comment: If you're developing under windows and use Visual Studio, try [Concurrency Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer) by Microsoft. It's very useful extension for diagnostic concurrency problems in application. Unfortunately it doesn't work well with netcore projects and doesn't show managed stack traces, but it should be fixed someday

Comment: @SAOBab00n tbh, i have seen other posts on here about specific issues with poor parallel performance, and possible issues with the F# implementation (though i sort of doubt this)....if you search in the F# tag you should turn up something

Comment: A suggestion: My understanding is `Array.Parallel` is more well suited to small jobs of a few ms. What is the performance like if you construct a `Task array` then use `Task.WaitAll`?

Comment: @JL0PD: One of my co-devs tried this and VS crashed... Not that it takes anything away from your suggestion - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should close this up.

The general answer was to avoid allocations even further than what we already did - and maybe even more importantly to not do any "cleaning" through the calculation.

I.e. instead of deleting subjects no longer being calculated to reduce the amount of work performed, we ended up keeping all objects and collections alive and in stead marking them as "out of calculation" thus not causing GC to collect discarded subjects.

So in the end quite a bit of mutability has been introduced. The current runtimes are: 8 minutes serial, 40 secs parallelising over subjects, 10:30 mins  when parallelization is over calculations for 16 calculations on my 16 core machine. Thus the original problem of relatively poor performance of the by calculation parallelization has been solved.

Thanks for the inputs provided for my general (bordering on ill-formed) question.